# Amazon Web Store Inventory as RSS/Data feed

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have been reviewing the setup of a current [Amazon Web Store](http://webstore.amazon.com/) implementation to figure out some of the systems capabilities. The end goal is to pull a feed that i can reuse and transform for Channel Adviser. The documentation on Amazon Web Store is a little sparse and I'm wondering if anyone here has a little experience with this specific product scenario (pull inventory from Web Store Account).

The current goal is to pull down the inventory for the store in a feed via RSS or any other suitable format. I have been looking at the [RSS web feeds for Tags @ amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/gp/tagging/rss-help.html) page but I dont think it's available for the web store product or feasible to pull an entire store's inventory this way.

-my research has led me to the [amazon product advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html) but looking at the [WSDL](http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/AWSECommerceService.wsdl) for the service, the only relevant service calls I see are ItemSearch, ItemLookup and SimilarityLookup; none of these seem to explicitly support Web Store and they dont really seem entirely appropriate for pulling the Web Store's entire inventory (although they do appear to accept a merchant ID). Does anyone know of a common or appropriate way to get access to this data?

Thanks in advance for any specific guidance you can provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a couple of contacts with Amazon Seller support, it appears that the most appropriate solution is to set up an Amazon Marketplace Web Services account and use those apis. The '**Inventory**' api seems to be exactly what we were after (although the support email suggested the Reports section).

> ### Response from Amazon Seller Support
>
> We checked and we have a different program that fits your needs called MWS (Market Place Web Service), you would have to sign up for an account first which is for free. Please visit this link to find out more information:
>
> https://developer.amazonservices.com/
>
> Click on reports and then on Amazon MWS Developer Guide (PDF) and you will be able to get more information related to your concern.

Comment: Do you still use the MWS apis? I have over 12,000 active items, and my inventory reports are only returning about 7500. :/

Comment: I don't have any active projects using them now to confirm a paging issue but my initial though would be either an issue with paging logic or that you have some variations of your products that are grouped (Like different sizes/colors of the same shirt). If neither of those is the case, reaching out to Amazon support would probably be the best bet.

Comment: Amazon support was a joke. One guy told me that inventory reports can only hold 7k items, and then told me he would forward it to someone who would know better. They emailed two days later and told me to go to "inactive" items and make them "active" (lol). -- I was able to accomplish what I was after by changing the prices up/down a cent, and waiting several hours. This still left about 12 things though, so I had to write a chrome extension to check the listing_ids on each of the 15 pages against a local DB. Dirty, but we can actually do inventory now. =/